# cfquery inside of cfoutput query results

Tags: sql, coldfusion

Looking for a more efficient way to insert records based on query results.

Example:

```
<cfoutput query="actionInfo">
<cfquery datasource="cfdev">
insert into dbo.buttonActions
(fID, bID, fieldID, aClear, aPress, aCheck, aUncheck, aCheckAll, aUncheckAll, tID)
values
('#newID#', '#bID#', '#fieldID#', '#aClear#', '#aPress#', '#aCheck#', '#aUncheck#', '#aCheckAll#', '#aUncheckAll#', '#tID#')
</cfquery>
</cfoutput>
```

This will run through and make a new insert into the database for each loop through the cfoutput. I've tried placing the cfoutput inside of the cfquery, but run into errors each time.

UPDATE:

This is what ended up working for me, based on Dan's example:

```
<cfquery datasource = "dsn">
insert into newTable
(fID, field1, field2, etc)
select '#newID#', field1, field2, etc -- the sql from q1
</cfquery>
```

Comment: A) What is your DBMS? B) Do you actually need a loop? If the source and target tables exist in the same database and/or on the same database, it is possible you do not need a loop. C) Usually the most efficient method of bulk inserting data is to use your db's bulk loading tools. Those vary by dbms, but you did not mention which one you are using. (Side note, *always* use cfqueryparam with variable query parameters. Especially when looping)

Comment: One other thing to keep in mind: when you put a cfquery inside of a cfoutput, you are making a new connection to the database for every row returned in your original query. That can be a huge bottleneck. I'd follow Dan's suggestion and try to put it all in one query or Leigh's suggestion and use the DB's bulk data load tools.

Comment: @Leigh Thanks for the good suggestions.  I've been steadily converting my code over to cfqueryparam once I learned about about it.  And yes, the huge bottleneck is what I'm trying to avoid.  Would like to write this up with just a SQL query, no loop.  Looking at Dan's suggestion, but need a bit more info to make it happen.

Comment: @Phil - Well the answers to the questions above will determine exactly what options are available to you :).  Can you take another look and tell us A) Which dbms you are using, SQL Server, MySQL, etcetera. (BTW, SQL syntax often varies by vendor, so always a good idea to specify your DBMS with any query questions). b) Also, what is the source of #actionInfo#? Is the data in that query from another table in the same database, a different db the same server, external server, spreadsheet ...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the initial query and the inserts are in the same database, you might need only one query.  This is what you are doing now;

```
<cfquery name="q1" datasource = "dsn">
select field1, field2, etc
</cfquery>

<cfoutput query="q1">
<cfquery datasource = "dsn">
insert into newTable
(field1, field2, etc)
values
(#field1#, #field2#, #etc#)
</cfquery.
</cfoutput>
```

What you could do instead is this:

```
<cfquery datasource = "dsn">
insert into newTable
(field1, field2, etc)
select field1, field2, etc -- the sql from q1
</cfquery>
```

Depending on a number of things, this approach might even be available if the databases are different.

That's one suggestion.  You mentioned putting the cfoutput inside the query.  Here is an approach you may not have thought of.  Using the same q1 from above,

```
<cfquery datasource="dsn">
insert into newTable
(field1, field2, etc)
select null, null, etc
from newTable
where 1=2
<cfloop query="q1">
union
select #q1.field1[currentrow]#, #q1.field2[currentrow]#, etc
from newTable
</cfloop>
</cfquery>
```

You'll have to experiment with this approach.  I've seen it run faster than what you are doing now, and I've also seen it run slower.

The bottom line is, you do have options, including your current approach.  There are times when I find it's best for the situation at hand.

Comment: If you need to eliminate dupes in q1, use the UNION. If dupes are OK or expected, use UNION ALL.

Comment: Learning all the time, thanks for the good info Dan.  I'd like to try your first suggestion, but how would I pass in the #newID# value that I'm gaining from a query up the line a bit?  Basically I'm needing to copy a bunch of rows, but change out the fID field on the copies.  Hope that makes sense.

Comment: You asked a general question and got a general answer.  If you are doing something in ColdFusion to generate data, such as new IDs, I suggest that you ask another question, one that is more specific.